# How to set object id as div id in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set my object id as div id but when I try running my app I'm getting an error saying

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing
```

Another error from the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'io.getstream.core.models.EnrichedActivity' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Here's my html code:

```
<div typeIdFieldName="id" th:id="${#strings.trim(object['id'])}" class="c-default-item" th:each="object : ${objects}"></div>
```

Comment: What's your stacktrace? `${#strings.trim(object['id'])}` looks questionable to me, what do you mean by this expression?

Comment: @Miha_x64 ${#strings.trim(object['id'])} means that I am setting my div id from `io.getstream.core.models.Enrichedobject` id value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `io.getstream.core.models.EnrichedActivity` has a `getID()` getter method name which when accessed using `th:id="${object.id}"` will throw a exception

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'io.getstream.core.models.EnrichedActivity' - maybe not public or not valid?.
```

In order to avoid this error, I used the getter method (`th:id="${object.getID()}"`) instead of accessing the property directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
th:id="${object.id}"
```

assuming that each object of the list iterated by `th:each="object : ${objects}"` contains an "id" attribute, a getter for it in the shape of `getId(){...}`, and the model has a list of objects called "objects".